# Responsive div with aspect ratio on both width and height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make my player div be responsive on height side. Currently if I resize width, div scales down, but if I resize height, it doesnt. And the scrollbar does not help because of lightbox-wrap div which is fixed I guess.

Is there a way to make player div responsive on height as well? (without changing lightbox-wrap being fixed)

https://jsfiddle.net/x723zrde/7/

```css
.lightbox-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.lightbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 520px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.player {
  position: relative;
  background: #ad3;
}

.player:after {
  padding-top: calc(56.25%);
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
  <div class="lightbox-wrap">

    <div class="lightbox">

      <div class="player"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While width can be attached to the window by default, height only changes with the content inside the div. But if you can bind it to an event (like window resize) you can do it with Javascript.

> Note that, i just used arbitrary values, in order to demonstrate. You can play with the numbers, or even change how the parent containers **(.lightbox)** resize by using `.style.transform`. The rest is all up to you.

```js
var players = document.getElementsByClassName("player");
window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var desired_h = h-100; // You can play with it;
var desired_w = desired_h*16/9;
    for (var i = players.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        players[i].style.height = desired_h+"px";
        players[i].style.width = desired_w +"px";
    }
});
```

```css
.lightbox-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.lightbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 520px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.player {
  position: relative;
  background: #ad3;
}

.player:after {
  padding-top: calc(56.25%);
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox-wrap">

    <div class="lightbox">

      <div class="player"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid javascript. So there is no css that can resize on both sides responsively?

Comment: I respect that. But still curious why someone would want to avoid JS, unless special.